# Why is NewRelic not receiving any data from my Heroku app?

Tags: node.js, heroku, newrelic

I'm running [this Node app on Heroku](https://github.com/awendt/ghost-on-heroku).

I've gone through the following steps:

1. Added the add-on to my application. Heroku added two env vars to my app, `NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY` and `NEW_RELIC_LOG`. I added third one, `NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME`.
2. Followed the instructions in the [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic#node-js-installation-and-configuration) and installed the newrelic module:

   ```
   npm install newrelic --save
   ```
3. Committed and pushed the [resulting change](https://github.com/awendt/ghost-on-heroku/commit/a4846e1955ea6f0daa43594c16ae9f55ff32016d) to `package.json`.

(I've skipped copying `newrelic.js` to the root because NewRelic [does not mention it in their Heroku-specific docs](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/hosting-services/nodejs-agent-heroku) and Heroku doesn't either.)

I still see no data in NewRelic. **What am I missing?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out: Yes, I did need to copy `newrelic.js` and a change the `server.js` to `require('newrelic')` (see [commit here](https://github.com/awendt/ghost-on-heroku/commit/92e3874976715add9c7fb0fa442c26a008fa6d8a)).